# ERROR Convertir string a integer para almacenar en IntPtr

Tags: vb.net

Necesito pasar un valor de tipo string a IntPtr.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente método:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea para saltarme ese error?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que los enteros tienen un límite, en este caso estás excediendo esos límites, declara IntPtrDest como "Long" y usa:

```
IntPtrDest = CLng(mystring)
```

Comment: El máximo valor de un Int es 2147483647, en el caso que muestras, la conversión da 3260933515. Este valor no puede ser manejado por el Int, pero sí por el Long.